# Why SN8 needed 12.5 km?

Tags: mission-design, spacex-starship

Is there a particular reason for chosing 12.5 km for the SN8 hop?

Why 5 km for example is not good enough?

Comment: They wanted 20K, but had to settle with the FAA for 12.5K.

Comment: Why is 20km too much for FAA?

Comment: I can't find a source, but I seem to recall some concern about high level winds causing it to be reduced at the last minute. Possibly they were concerned about debris traveling downwind after a high altitude explosion.